# Passing Object from controller to view then to other controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my controller i have:

TestController

```
def show_result

  @myObject = Object.where(.....)
end

def export_result
  .....
end
```

how can i call the "export_result" method from the view using the same object @myObject, without doing again the same query ?

Comment: If you want to call some function from the view, why don't you put that function in the helpers and include that helper in the controller? I think that's what you want to do, right?

Comment: you should not call `controllers action` from `view`, you should define a `helper method` for this..

Comment: Thanks all, but how can i call this helper methode using a button or link_to or javascript (onClick) function ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to understand the instance variable first.
The instance variable is destroyed when its object is destroyed.
In a word, the @myObject variable is available for each action(request).

The answer:
1. using callback
you can make a simple method to prepare rendering and call it.

```
    before_filter :load_object, only: [:show_result, :export_result]

    def load_object
      @myObject = Object.where(...)
    end
```

1. call show_result method in export_result
   this is not right method if show_result has render code or some other code that will not be used in export_result method.